# how to unit test react reduxsauce saga using jest and enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs, redux-saga

I am new to react and redux. 
I am developing a project and for that I want to have redux, by using reduxsauce and redux-saga, but I am struggling to write unit tests for these.
Here is my folder structure:
[image]

My App-test.js:

```
import App from '../../../assets/src/App'
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import createStore from './Redux'


describe('App', () => {

const initialState = {output:100}
    const mockStore = configureStore()
    let store,container
        const store = createStore()
    beforeEach(()=>{
        store = mockStore(initialState)
        container = shallow(<App store={store} /> )
    })


  it('renders correctly', () => {
    const rendered = renderer.create(
      <App/>
    );
    expect(rendered.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Here is my App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Index from './Screens/Index';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import createStore from './Redux'

const store = createStore()

const rootElement = document.getElementById('subscription');

export default class App extends React.Component {

render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Index />
      </Provider>
    );
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I have tried with both the mockStore and store variable, but I am getting following error:

[image]

Any suggestions what could be wrong here?

Thanks

### UPDATE 1

I muted the code now for shallow, and now my App-test.js file looks like this:

```
import App from '../../../assets/src/App'
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import createStore from './Redux'


describe('App', () => {

const initialState = {output:100}
    const mockStore = configureStore()
    let store,container
        const store = createStore()
//    beforeEach(()=>{
////        store = mockStore(initialState)
//        container = shallow(<App store={store} /> )
//    })


  it('renders correctly', () => {
    const rendered = renderer.create(
      <App/>
    );
    expect(rendered.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

But I get different error now:

[image]

### UPDATE 2

After trying the solution as suggested by Rami Enbashi in the answer, the previous error (before UPDATE 1) again started appearing.

Comment: I don't see `shallow` being imported. Are you sure you are using Enzyme's 'shallow' ?

Comment: @RamiEnbashi I have updated my question with an edit, please have a look, I am getting different error now after I muted beforeEach

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a transpilation issue. You need to register Babel so that it will transpile ES6 to ES5 before you run unit tests. One way to do it is this.

In `package.json` add this jest config:

```
  "jest": {
     "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./scripts/testsetup.js"
  }
```

and in `testsetup.js` add this

```
require('babel-register')();
require("babel-polyfill");
require("babel-jest");
.....
```

Make sure you read Jest documentation for more config or needed plugins. And make sure you install them first.

Comment: Actually after trying this out it again started complaining with the previous error, that is before my UPDATE 1 in the description.

Comment: Can you try moving `beforeEach` and store mocking code outside your test and have them at the root level of the file and make sure you are importing 'shallow' from 'enzyme'?

Comment: Nope, that didnt help, it still gives the same error.